# Unable to delete pdf after opened by PDFRenderer

Tags: java

I have seen another question regarding this topic.
I tried but it still not working for me

My code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Testing\\abc.pdf");
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
ReadableByteChannel ch = Channels.newChannel(new FileInputStream(file));
FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

/* The rest code to convert pdf to image 
 * according to number of pages in pdf given above, which will not be provided here 
 */

/* Closing file */
raf.close();
ch.close();
channel.close();
buf.clear();
```

My code doesn't work, it didn't close the file

I cannot remove the file after my program is ran, it said that Java SE Binary Platform has opened this file.

How can I close the file opened by PDFRenderer?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer/R8/core-renderer-R8-sources.jar!/org/xhtmlrenderer/simple/PDFRenderer.java?format=ok

Comment: have you closed `pdffile`?

Comment: I wish I could close it, but trying to close it by using pdffile.close() will result in "cannot find symbol"

I read your link Algorithmist, thanks but I didn't use OutputStream, so I don't know whether they are useful to me or not

Comment: i think the problem is in the third line, you opened a FileInputstream in the argument but you did not close it.

Comment: After you mentioned it, I tried to close the FileInputStream, however after closing it, the result is same

Answer (score 0):

remove the extra ')' from the first and third lines.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Testing\\abc.pdf")); //last ')' one
ReadableByteChannel ch = Channels.newChannel(new FileInputStream(file)); //last ')' one
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry, It was a typo, I carelessly typed an extra ')' into my code after I pasted it

Comment: The error seems to be in the unshown rest (or closing the fileChannel).

PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(new File(file));
PdfReader pdfReader = pdfFile.getPdfReader();
try {
    ...
} finally {
    pdfReader.close();
}

Comment: I just removed the missing code, only to find the problem still exist.
I managed to find out it's probably the problem of ByteBuffer, but I dont know how to fix it